# Reducing propositional logic statements

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am having some trouble with reducing some propositional logic statements.

The first one is as follows:

$\neg(P \lor Q) \lor \neg (P \lor \neg Q)$.

I used deMorgan's law to change this to:

$(\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P \land Q)$

Is there anything I can do to reduce this further?

---

The second one is:

$(P \lor Q) \leftrightarrow (\neg P \land Q)$

I have no idea where to even start on this one.

Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> (not(P or Q) or not (P or not Q).
>
> I used deMorgan's law to change this to:
>
> (not P and not Q) or (not P and Q)

$$\begin{align}\neg (P\lor Q)\lor \neg (P\lor \neg Q) & \equiv (\neg P\land \neg Q)\lor (\neg P\land Q) & \textsf{de'Morgan's Laws}
\\ & \equiv \neg P \land (\neg Q\lor Q) & \textsf{Distribution}
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from there?

---

> ((P or Q) iff (not P and Q)

First use $A\leftrightarrow B \equiv (A\land B)\lor(\neg A\land \neg B)$

$$\begin{align}(P\lor Q)\leftrightarrow (\neg P\land Q) 
& \equiv \big( (P\lor Q)\land(\neg P\land Q) \big) \lor \big(\neg (P\lor Q)\land \neg (\neg P\land Q) \big)
\end{align}$$

Now simplify...

Comment: Ok, so I realize by looking at it that the first part of that ((P∨Q)∧(¬P∧Q)) can be simplified to (¬P∧Q), but what steps do I need to show to get to that?

The second part can be simplified to (¬P∧¬Q), but again, I don't know the steps to prove it.